# comparing user input values with all other values in a table in the database

Tags: web2py

In my web2py controller i have a function comparing a user input value against values in a table in a database but the problem is only the first value in the database is compared, the second one and others after it are not compared to the value entered by the user!!!
**CODE:**

```
def bMarket():
key=db(db.regKeys).select(db.regKeys.ALL)
for k in key:
    if request.vars.regCode == k.regKey:
        message="Correct Key"
        return DIV(message, _style="color: white; border: solid 1px green; width: 160px; background-color: green; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:5px;")
    else:
        return DIV("Incorrect Key", _id="regCodeTarget", _style="color: white; border: solid 1px red; width: 160px; background-color: red; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:5px;")<br />
```

What am i doing wrong??? How do i get to compare the user entered value against **ALL OTHER VALUES IN THE DATABASE AND NOT JUST THE FIRST ONE??**Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the `for` loop checks the key, and if it does not match, it immediately returns the "Incorrect Key" response. Instead, you should loop through all the records and only return "Incorrect Key" after the looping has completed:

```
def bMarket():
    key=db(db.regKeys).select(db.regKeys.ALL)
    for k in key:
        if request.vars.regCode == k.regKey:
            message="Correct Key"
            return DIV(message, _style="color: white; border: solid 1px green; width: 160px; background-color: green; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:5px;")
    return DIV("Incorrect Key", _id="regCodeTarget", _style="color: white; border: solid 1px red; width: 160px; background-color: red; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:5px;")
```

But that method is very inefficient, as it requires loading all the records from the database into a Python object and then looping through each record in Python. Instead, you should simply handle the lookup directly via a database query (which doesn't require loading any data from the database):

```
def bMarket():
    key_exists = not db(db.regKeys.regKey == request.vars.regCode).isempty()
    if key_exists:
        return DIV(...)
    else:
        return DIV(...)
```

To make the lookup even faster, you can create an index on the `regKey` column in the database.